# Best way to test perl -pi -e one-liner before execution?

Tags: regex, perl

I don't know any Perl, but I do occasionally use "[perl pie](http://technosophos.com/2009/05/21/perl-pie-if-you-only-learn-how-do-one-thing-perl-it.html)" (`perl -pi -e`) to do a batch regex find and replace, e.g. change `a` to `e` in all the .txt files in a folder `perl -pi -e 's|a|e|g' *.txt`.

Is there any way to do a "dry run" so that I can preview the change? I'm frequently using moderately complex regexes with positive / negative lookaheads / lookbehinds, group references, etc., and I'm often not 100% sure I have it right on the first run. It would be *wonderful* to have something like [rename.pl](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.6/bin/rename.PL)'s `-n` flag, which doesn't change anything, only outputs the changes that would have been made.

Currently, my strategy is to just use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com), which accepts a Perl regex, to make sure my match string is correct, and go from there. Is there a better way? Anything like `rename -n`?

Also open to something other than `perl` if I'm missing something awesome, though I am partial to its regex format.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `-i` parameter from your perl code to do a dry run.

```
perl -pe 's|a|e|g' *.txt
```

From `perl --help`,

```
-i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

To print the particular line where the replacement occurs.

```
$ cat file
abcd
cbcb
foo
$ perl -nle 'print if s|a|e|g' file
ebcd
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as stated I only want to output the change (not the entire file contents).

Comment: if you want to print a particular line where the change occur the you need to add `-n` instead of `-p` parameter. `perl -nle 'print if s|a|e|g' file`

Comment: Great, thanks! The following brings it a little closer to the rename.pl output by showing which file is being matched, but that definitely answers the question. `perl -ne 'if (s|a|e|g) { print "$ARGV\t"; print }' *.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions.

1. Remove the `-i` parameter so the modified files are printed to the console
2. Specify a backup extension `-i.bak`, so you can observe the changes and revert if necessary

Either way, I would test without the glob `*.txt` and instead work on a single file until you're sure that is working correctly.

I would probably lean toward the second option with a single file.  That way you can easily do a `diff` to observe the changes that took place.

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's|a|e|g' sample.txt
$ diff sample.txt sample.txt.bak
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was hoping for, as the `diff` would output only the change. I think the best answer may be a combination of the first and second solutions, `for f in *.txt; do diff <(perl -pe 's|a|e|g' "$f") "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@8henrie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26210660/1870254), the following shows the changes as git would:

`for f in *.txt; do perl -pe 's/a/e/g' "$f" |  git diff --no-index -- - "$f"; done`

after checking you can perform the actual replacement using:

`perl -pi -e 's/a/e/g' *.txt`